# An exercise about $X$-invariant in automorphism groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $U \leq G$ such that $G = NU$. Then there exists a bijection, preserving inclusion, from the set of subgroups $X$ satisfying $U \leq X \leq G$ to the set of $U$-invariant subgroups $Y$ satisfying $U\cap N \leq Y \leq N$.

I have no idea about how to solve it, and any help is sincerely appreciated.

**PS**: I've always been confused about the concept of "$X$-invariant", so I would like to be told more details. Thanks!

Comment: The correspondence is given by $Y = X \cap N$. Saying that $Y$ is $U$-invariant is equivalent to $U \le N_G(Y)$, which is true, because $U$  normalizes both $X$ and $N$. To show that this is a bijection, you need to show that $UY \cap N = Y$ for all $U$-invariant $Y$ with $U \cap N \le Y \le N$.

Comment: There’s no question about $U\leq N_G(Y)$; but, doesn’t it have to take all automorphisms instead of only the conjugation for $Y$ to be $U$-invariant? Thanks for your time! : )

Comment: To say that $Y$ is $U$-invariant means that $Y$ is invariant under conjugation by all elements of $U$, which is equivalent to $U \le N_G(Y)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes I see. And why $UY\cap N=Y$ implies bijectivity?

Comment: I think you should try and solve it yourself now.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh, sorry. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. I solved it with Dedekind identity : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Proof.*
>
> For each $X$, $U$ is a subgroup of $X$, hence normalizes $X$; $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so $U$ certainly normalizes $N$. Thus, $U$ normalizes $X\cap N$, i.e., $X\cap N$ is $U$-invariant. Now we can define a map
>       \begin{align*}
>  \varphi~:~\mathfrak{A}=\{ X\mid U\le X\le G \} &\longrightarrow \mathfrak{B}=\{Y\mid Y \mbox{ is a }U\mbox{-invariant subgroup}\}\\X&\longmapsto X\cap N.
>  \end{align*}
>   The map is well defined since $U\leq N_G(X\cap N)$.
>
> For the injectivity: $\forall\, X_1\cap N,X_2\cap N\in \mathfrak{B}$, if $X_1\cap N=X_2\cap N$, then by **Dedekind Identity**, $X_1=U(X_1\cap N)=U(X_2\cap N)=X_2$.
>
> The map is also surjective. $\forall\, Y\in \mathfrak{B}$, $u\in U$, since $Y$ is $U$-invariant, $Y^u=u^{-1}Yu=Y$, $Yu=uY$. Hence, $YU=UY$, $YU\leq G$. Note that $U\cap N\leq U$, $NU=G$, $(U\cap N)U\subseteq YU\subseteq NU\Longrightarrow U\leq YU\leq G$. So we can apply **Dedekind Identity** to $YU$, $YU=UY=U(UY\cap N)\Longrightarrow Y=UY\cap N$. Since $UY\in \mathfrak{A}$, each $Y$ has a corresponding $X\in \mathfrak{A}$, therefore $\varphi$ is surjective.
>
> The bijection is hence proved.